# How to execute multiple queries in for loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I want to execute multiple queries in for loop of postgresql.

For example

```
FOR rec IN select * from student LOOP

END LOOP;
```

In above example select * from student is only one single query, I have multiple queries on which I want to loop. I want to use the same loop not multiple loops for multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

How would the various queries be related to each other?

**(1) Combine the 1st, 2nd etc from each, according to their respective sort order.**

You could put each query in a subquery with `row_number()` and then link them all on the row_number and run a single loop over all ...

```
FOR rec IN
  SELECT *
  FROM  (
     SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY student_id) AS rn
     FROM   student
     ) s
  FULL JOIN  (
     SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY foo_id) AS rn
     FROM   foo
     ) t USING (rn)
  -- etc.
LOOP
  -- do stuff
END LOOP;
```

Use a [`FULL [ OUTER ] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) if the number of rows might not match and you don't want to lose any.

*Alternatively* you could loop through *one* query (the one with the most rows, preferrably) and open [**a cursor**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html) for your other queries. Then you can `FETCH [NEXT]` in every iteration of the loop as you please and for as many cursors as you want.

**(2) Cross join - combine every row with every row from the next query.**

Unlikely, because it would quickly produce huge numbers of combinations for multiple query. Either way, remove `row_number()` from the above and just cross join your queries.
Or nest the loops; Same effect, just more expensive.

Comment: Thanks. But here in my situation I have single table where there are few duplicates. I have identified them by using select clause. Now I want to remove them keeping single record(removing duplicates) . I dont want to access multiple tables.